# ListBox with unknown type items - how to move items up/down

Tags: c#, wpf

There are many samples on how to move `ListBoxItem` up or down - but only if `ListBox.ItemsSource` type is known.

Can anyone help share some more generic code, if `ListBox.ItemsSource` type is simply `IEnumerable`?

I need such code to move `ListBoxItem` up/down, regardless if `ItemsSource` was set in XAML, code-behind or ViewModel. In the latter case it will, most likely, be an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13715448/285795

Comment: No, that sample has typed items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the list into objects. Here is an example that takes the last item and moves it to the first item during a double click event:

```
private void LbFiles_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceList = lbFiles.ItemsSource
                            .OfType<object>()
                            .ToList();

    var moveLast = sourceList[sourceList.Count - 1];

    sourceList.RemoveAt(sourceList.Count - 1);

    var newList = new List<object>() { moveLast };

    newList.AddRange(sourceList);

    lbFiles.ItemsSource = newList;
}
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="FileNames" Type="system:String">
            <system:String>C:\Temp\Alpha.txt</system:String>
            <system:String>C:\Temp\Beta.txt</system:String >
            <system:String>C:\Temp\Gamma.txt</system:String >
        </ x:Array >
    </ StackPanel.Resources >

    <ListBox Name = "lbFiles"
             ItemsSource = "{StaticResource FileNames}"
             MouseDoubleClick = "LbFiles_MouseDoubleClick"
             Margin = "10" />
</ StackPanel >
```

Here it is in action

[image]